# how to pass multiple values in a single php variable through a link using logical or

Tags: php, variables, url

I am using a switch case in php and trying to access multiple values in a single variable

see the code below :

```
switch($_GET['case'])
{
case 1:
if(isset[$_GET['a']]){
 echo $x;}

case 2:
echo $y;

case 3:
if(isset[$_GET['b']]){
echo $z;}
}
```

and when i click on this link :

```
<a href=?case=1OR3>link</a>
```

then i want to access both the cases : 
1.if a is set then it will echo $x.
2.or if b is set then it will echo $z.

How this can be done any idea ..??

**UPDATE:**

```
switch($_GET['case'])
 {
case 0;
//only search active
if(isset($_GET['s1'])){
$radio=$_SESSION['r1'];

$construct ="$radio LIKE '%$search_each%'";
$getq2_= "$radio LIKE '%$search_each%'";
 break;
}

case 1;
//search and pub active
if(isset($_GET['px'])){
echo "<script>  alert('case1'); </script>";
$construct = "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '%$search_each%' AND Publisher LIKE     '%".$_GET['pub']."%'";
$getq2_= $construct;
 break;
}


case 2;
//search and sub active
if(isset($_GET['sx'])){
echo "<script>  alert('case2'); </script>";
$construct = "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '%$search_each%' AND Subject LIKE '%".$_GET['sub']."%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_SESSION['pub']."%'";

$getq2_= "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '%$search_each%' AND Subject LIKE '%".$_SESSION['sub']."%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_GET['pub']."%'";
$z=array("Odontology","Oral Pathology","Orthodontology","Oral and     Maxillofacial Surgery     ","Prosthodontology","Periodontology","Endodontology","Oral and Maxillofacial     Radiology","Esthetic Dentistry","Pediatric Dentistry","Public Health     Dentistry");

if($_GET['sub']==true)
{
    $getq3_[$_GET['sub']] = "(Subject LIKE '%".$_GET['sub']."%' AND $radio     LIKE '%$search_each%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_GET['pub']."%') ";
}
break;
}


case 3;

//only alphabets active
if(isset($_SESSION['hx']) && !empty($_SESSION['hx']))
{echo "<script>  alert('case3'); </script>";
$radio=$_SESSION['r1'];

$construct ="$radio LIKE '$search_each%'";
$getq2_= "$radio LIKE '$search_each%'";

break;
}



case 4;
//alphabets and pub active
if(isset($_GET['px']) && isset($_SESSION['hx']) && !empty($_SESSION['hx'])){

echo "<script>  alert('case4'); </script>";
$construct = "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '$search_each%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_GET['pub']."%'";
$getq2_= $construct;
 break;
}


case 5;
//alphabets and sub active
if(isset($_GET['sx']) && isset($_SESSION['hx']) && !empty($_SESSION['hx']))
{
echo "<script>  alert('case5'); </script>";
$construct = "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '$search_each%' AND Subject LIKE '%".$_GET['sub']."%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_SESSION['pub']."%'";

$getq2_= "".$_SESSION['r1']." LIKE '$search_each%' AND Subject LIKE         '%".$_SESSION['sub']."%' AND Publisher LIKE '%".$_GET['pub']."%'";
 break;
}


}
```

Thats why i was not using if else for them it 'll be very complex , So is it possible ..???

Comment: I think you should do a switch on `$_GET['a']` or `$_GET['b']` and then cases are `true` and `false` So for example `switch($_GET['a']) { case true: echo $x; break; case false: echo $z; break;}`

Comment: what you want to do actually

Comment: You should use a `if/else` statement rather than a `switch/case` here.

Comment: Switch isn't a good choice for this task, use a set of `if-elseif` conditions.

Comment: Actually i am using switch for 6 cases 1st three for one condition and last three for another condition that is a and b and their is huge code for this so can not use if else for all of them switch case would be better ,So this is the only i found to achieve it ...

Comment: Then show us your whole code so that we can tell you. Because here `"if a is set then it will echo $x. 2.or if b is set then it will echo $z."` this is a `if/elseif` condition. :)

Comment: ok i am writing it just wait for a while

Comment: Have you heard of SQL injection? You should really escape your variables before you insert them in your SQL statements...

Comment: Yeah but how would that be helpful can you please explain !!.. i just simply  want to access multiple values in a variable isn't their any trick or something  i think its possible its not that hard ..??